# How order a view result by reduced value? CouchDB

Tags: javascript, couchdb

Can I order the result of a view by the value, returned by reduced?

```
{
    "rows": [
        {"key":"bob","value":2},
        {"key":"john","value":3},
        {"key":"zztop","value":1}
     ]
}
```

I wanna a result like this:

```
{
    "rows": [
        {"key":"zztop","value":1},
        {"key":"bob","value":2},
        {"key":"john","value":3}

     ]
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this in PHP or JS!?

Comment: I'm doing in Ruby on Rails using CouchRest gem. But the json is bigger than this simple example.

Comment: show what your Map function looks like

Answer (score 1):

you just want to sort the `rows` array by the `value` property of each object? you can specify a custom comparison method for the js `sort` method.

```
myResult.rows.sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseInt(a.value,10) - parseInt(b.value,10);
});
```

parameters `a` and `b` will each be an entry from the `rows` array. the method returns an `int` value of greather than 0, 0, or less than zero. greater than 0 means `a` should be ordered before `b`, the opposite for less than 0, and 0 means they are equal.

Comment: The question is about how to do that on CouchDB. Of course we can manually sort the results after getting them. But what if there are more results returned than can be stored in memory, for instance ?

Answer (score 1):

I would just build it into the key...

```
{"key": [1, "zztop"], "value": "whateverYouWant"},
{"key": [2, "bob"], "value": "whateverYouWant"},
{"key": [3, "john"], "value": "whateverYouWant"}
```

In order to search for a specific key, use a startkey/endkey query like this:

```
http://XXXXXX/database/_design/name/_view/name?startkey=[[0,"zztop"]]&endkey=[[999,"zztop"]]
```

As long as your value is numerical, just make the endkey larger than the largest possible value and this query should return the results for "zztop."

It's sloppy, but I have yet to find a better CouchDB sorting method. All-in-all, you might be better sorting in your application.